# Import Database to JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pouchdb

I am working on electron js application and pouchdb
i want to import the created database to another js file and want to retrieve the data

Here is a File structure

```
 -JS
    - impotdb.js        // want to import db here

 -DB                    // this folder contains all db
    -DB1
    -DB2

  db.js                //this is main db.js file where db is created
```

here is db.js code

```
var PouchDB = require("pouchdb");
var db = new PouchDB("DB/Db1", { adapter: "leveldb" });
console.log("Database created Successfully.");
```

i tried with [pouchdb-all-dbs](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-all-dbs) plugin but for me it returned as empty array

code for plugin in importdb.js file

```
var PouchDB = require("pouchdb");
require('pouchdb-all-dbs')(PouchDB);

PouchDB.allDbs().then(function (dbs) {
   // dbs is an array of strings, e.g. ['mydb1', 'mydb2']
    console.log(dbs)
  }).catch(function (err) {
    // handle err
    console.log(err)
});
```

on console log dbs it returned as empty array 
can any one help me to import and  use created dbs in importdb.js

Comment: The [allDbs plugin](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-all-dbs) works with the `PouchDB.on('created')` and `PouchDB.on('destroyed')` events.  It is unaware of databases created without the plugin present.

Comment: is there any way without alldbs plugin to import or replicate the data base to file

Comment: Look to the [PouchDB Dump](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-dump-cli) and [PouchDB Load](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-load) plugins.  Here's a relatively [recent fork of the Dump](https://github.com/catalpainternational/pouchdb-dump-cli) tool; the Load tool is old, so there may be work involved - if so, maybe contribute by forking that repo.  For what it's worth, here's a good [list of plugins](https://pouchdb.com/external.html) for pouchDB.